# Once upon a time, there

Tags: difference

What are the differences between the following sentences?

> 1. Once upon a time, **a lion lived** in the jungle.
> 2. Once upon a time, **there lived a lion** in the jungle.
> 3. Once upon a time, **there was a lion who lived** in the jungle.

Comment: There are no real differences. Number 2 is perhaps the most traditional.

Comment: The differences are in style. The first is a simple statement. The second and third are typical of the introductions to folk tales. People are unlikely to use such constructions in everyday speech.

Comment: The second is longer than the first, and the third is even longer... (in other words, please ask more specific questions)